# Best way to access an object's properties when it can contain another object inside of them

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have this type:

```
export type PersoanaType = {
    id: string,
    cnp: string,
    nume: string,
    prenume: string,
    educatie: string,
    email: string,
    experienta: string,
    judetDomiciliu: string,
    judetLimitrof1: string,
    judetLimitrof2: string,
    localitateDomiciliu: string,
    localitateLimitrof1: string,
    localitateLimitrof2: string,
    meserie1: string,
    meserie2: string,
    telefon: string
}
```

and I want to create a component based on this data, this way:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { PersoanaType } from "./PersoanaType";

type Props = {
    persoana: PersoanaType
}

export default function PersoanaDetails(props: Props) {
    return (
        <ul>
            {
                props.persoana &&
                Object.values(props.persoana).map((value, index) => 
                    <li key={index}>{(value as any)?.nume}</li>
                )
            }
        </ul>
    );
}
```

The problem is that some of the values are not objects so they don't contain the .nume attribute.

So, there isn't anything rendered.

My question is - what would be the best way to be able to show the string even if it's the property or an object and I have to access its .nume property?

thanks.

//Edit:

I changed my code to this for testing purposes. Here you can see the output.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { PersoanaType } from "./PersoanaType";

type Props = {
    persoana: PersoanaType
}

export default function PersoanaDetails(props: Props) {
    useEffect(function() {
                Object.values(props.persoana).map((value, index) => {
                    return console.log(value);
                })
    }, []);
    return (
        <ul>
            
        </ul>
    );
}
```

[image: photo]

Comment: `value` is a string. Strings don't have `nume` properties.

Comment: @kelly that's what I expected too. but please check my edit :)

Comment: can you add expected outputs?

Comment: @VinodLiyanage they should've been all strings

Comment: does my answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
const toString = (item) => {
  if(typeof item === 'string') return item;
  if(item instanceof Object) return JSON.stringify(item);
  return String(value);
}

export default function PersoanaDetails(props: Props) {
    useEffect(function() {
       Object.values(props.persoana).map((value, index) => toString(value))
    }, []);
    return <ul> </ul>  
}
```

Comment: I get "can't convert undefined to object" error.

Comment: looks like `props.persoana` is undefined. please check its value.